# Switch Stack Overflow account from Google login to Stack Exchange login

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, linked-accounts, google

Right now I have an account on Stack Overflow that was created automatically when I logged in using my Google account.

The point is, what happens if I lose access to my Google account?
It seemed unlikely when I registered, but now that Google accounts are tied to YouTube accounts, which can get closed for a number of reasons, I'm starting to worry.

I'd like to know if (and how) I can switch my Stack Overflow account from the Google-login to one that uses a dedicated password.

BTW I don't mind needing to remember one more password.

Comment: That is definitely one of the last sentences I would search on Google. I barely have an idea of what an OpenID is.

Comment: Yeah, that's true -- in fact that's one of the reasons why we have duplicates (note the comment is an automated message shown if you flag or close a question as a duplicate).

Comment: Good to know. I was worried this would get deleted even though it can be easier to spot.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. Adding OAuth providers to your account is distinctly different than adding a username/password StackExchange login, and I was specifically looking to find that out, not adding other OAuth providers.

Comment: You can add a password to your account while keeping your social network login (no need to pick one over another). To do this, go to the login form, click Forgot? and put in your email address to get the password reset link.

Comment: Oh btw, I think having your YouTube account closed would only mean you lose the ability to be a content creator in YouTube (using the said Google account) but other Google services would remain untouched (including, being a content consumer in YouTube).

Comment: Is it just me, or is this a really bad interface, where computer professionals and experts _cannot_ find how to log out (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294881/how-does-one-logout-from-stack-overflow), or how to change the login ID used and have to search for documentation of such basic tasks that are meaninglessly scattered (including account access *only* from Meta Stack Exchange)?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think the `my logins` tab does what you want. You can add your Facebook and SE account with your existing account.

[image]

Now if you are not sure of your Google account, make a Stack Exchange account and merge with your existing account (You can do that in the `my logins` tab itself). This is one account you can be sure of.

Comment: Well, that was quick. Thanks! It was not so easy to find an answer on Google, maybe upvoting this would help?

Comment: It worked, so I accepter your answer. I would also upvote if I had enough rep ;)

Comment: As far as I can see this does not work anymore, no SE login can be added.

Comment: Correction: It does work but since everyone gets an implicit SE login now you have to do a password recovery.

Comment: *Figured out how to add a stack exchange login to a Google Oauth account:* Log out of StackExchange, Create a new login with a username and password, click verification link in email, logout, Log back into your old account with Google OAuth, Go to StackExchange, Click your name in the top bar (to view your profile), Click "my logins", Click "add more logins", Click "log in with StackExchange", enter username and password.

Comment: The "login with StackExchange" has been deleted but you can still type "https://openid.stackexchange.com" in the OpenID slot and login using your new SE account there.